# Stored procedure and Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

I have stored Procedure getSalesOrder() returning a row structure like this:

Order (map with EF), customfield1 , customfield2 ,customfield3.

How can i use EntityFramework to get the order, and custom Fields Values ?

Comment: here is a good tutorial http://bit.ly/QPOIYw

Answer (score 3):

With the currently shipping Entity Framework, you can't. Stored procedures returning scalar values is, I believe, a feature scheduled for the .NET framework 4.0.